# Please explain how move method is working in Eloquent javascript Chapter 7

Tags: javascript

i'm looking at a move method of VillageState class here from [Eloquent javascript Chapter 7](https://eloquentjavascript.net/07_robot.html).

```
class VillageState {
  constructor(place, parcels) {
    this.place = place;
    this.parcels = parcels;
  }

  move(destination) {
    if (!roadGraph[this.place].includes(destination)) {
      return this;
    } else {
      let parcels = this.parcels.map(p => {
        if (p.place != this.place) return p;
        return {place: destination, address: p.address};
      }).filter(p => p.place != p.address);
      return new VillageState(destination, parcels);
    }
  }
}
```

i am unable to understand the else part of the move method.can you please explain what it is doing.

Comment: the else part maps over this.parcels then filters out any objects where place is not the same as address and returns a new instance with just those "parcels"

Answer (score 0):

The `else` branch does a few things:

1. It loops over the `parcels` instance property using `Array.prototype.map` which returns a new array.
2. The callback passed to `map` takes a `place` as an argument and checks if it matches `this.place`. If it does not, simply returns the place, otherwise returns a new object with the `place` property set to the provided `direction`.
3. The computed array from step 2 is then filtered to exclude all places where `p.place` is the same as `p.address`.
4. Finally, returns a new `VillageState` with the newly computed parcels.

We could describe each step individually:

Starting data:

```js
this.place = "one";
this.parcels = [{ place: "one", address: "one" }, { place: "two", address: "two" }, { place: "three", address: "two" }, { place: "four", address: "one" }];
```

After the call to `map` (assuming a `destination` of "ten"):

```js
parcels = [{ place: "ten", address: "one" }, { place: "two", address: "two" }, { place: "three", address: "two" }, { place: "four", address: "one" }];
```

After the call to filter:

```js
parcels = [{ place: "ten", address: "one" }, { place: "three", address: "two" }, { place: "four", address: "one" }];
```